# in the android"Android-Universal-Image-Loader" why should current task be cancelled if ImageView is reused for another task

Tags: task, universal-image-loader

In the class LoadAndDisplayImageTask,there is a function named "checkTaskIsNotActual".And there is a note "If ImageView is reused for another task then current task should be cancelled".But I don't know why did he do this.Cound any friend tell me the answer if know the reasion.

Answer (score 1):

This happens your views are generated from an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html)
To preserve memory and boost performance, the adapter will reuse the same view (an image view for instance) for different items (i.e. ImageView on item 1 is the same memory object with ImageView in item 20. The adapter will therefore just initialize the ImageView Objecct only once and change ts properties for item 1 and 20 respectively.

Now suppose that you want to display img1.jpg in ImageView of item 1 and img20.jpg in Image view in item 20.

your adapter will most likely trigger display image for both, but since they are sharing the same ImageView (i.e. only one of them is visible on screen) the "***checkTaskIsNotActual***" would stop img1.jpg to be displayed at item 20, because when item 20 is generated, ***the ImageView is reused***

I am actually having issues with this too. 
As I have many items on my list and most of them cancel the display task because the imageview is reused. 
This is ok as a result for me, but there seems to be a memory leak and when attempting with too many reused views the heap will exceed budget.

Comment: Thank your answer.Now I have got it.But you mentioned a issue, that will leak memory when use the universal-image-loader. Actually, I have not found this issue. Could you tell me more detail about the memory leak? Do you have some track？

Comment: Not as of now but will work more with it in the following moths probably. will keep you posted :)

Comment: Recently I have been using it and study it，and found its weaknesses, it is not suitable for big picture, such as the full-screen image. It is quite good for the list of small pictures.